# Strip Text in all List Items after Character in each list Item Python

Tags: python, list, text, strip, partition

I have a list:

```
ip_info = ['10.0.0.2/10.10.10.1', '10.0.111.1/10.10.121.4', '10.0.145.15/10.99.10.1', '10.99.0.1/10.44.155.4', '10.0.10.1/10.10.110.1']
```

I want to be able to strip all characters after the `/` character for each item in the list.

For a output of:

```
ip_info = ['10.0.0.2/', '10.0.111.1/', '10.0.145.15/', '10.99.0.1/', '10.0.110.1/']
```

From there I will be able to remove the `/` without issue as they are all static and can be removed easily.

I have attempted:

```
for x  in ip_info:
    ''.join(ip_info.partition('/')[0:2])
```

I don't think this is correct. As it needs to happen for each item in the list. Help?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `x.partition` rather than `ip_info.partition`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using list comprehensions:

```
ip_info = [ip.split('/')[0] for ip in ip_info]
```

---

```
>>> ip_info = ['10.0.0.2/10.10.10.1', '10.0.111.1/10.10.121.4', '10.0.145.15/10.99.10.1',
'10.99.0.1/10.44.155.4', '10.0.10.1/10.10.110.1']
>>> ip_info = [ip.split('/')[0] for ip in ip_info]
>>> print ip_info
['10.0.0.2', '10.0.111.1', '10.0.145.15', '10.99.0.1', '10.0.10.1']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> ip_info = ['10.0.0.2/10.10.10.1', '10.0.111.1/10.10.121.4', '10.0.145.15/10.99.10.1', '10.99.0.1/10.44.155.4', '10.0.10.1/10.10.110.1']
>>> [i.split('/')[0] for i in ip_info] 
['10.0.0.2', '10.0.111.1', '10.0.145.15', '10.99.0.1', '10.0.10.1']
```